Transport endpoint not connected
Whenever I run almost any command like sudo dpkg --configure -a, or some other command I get the error: transport endpoint is not connected.
I have tried almost everything, unmounting, rebooting, shutting down wsl, running apt install yet nothing works. Please help.

Please post the full error message

Since this is WSL, it should be very easy to remove it and recreate a new WSL instance  with identical packages

@ArchismanPanigrahi
the error message differs for every command I try to run; but includes the transport endpoint is not connected at every instance.
Also, can you kindly elaborate on what you mean by "recreate a new WSL instance" (I'm a total Linux noob)

By recreate a new WSL instance I mean delete WSL and reinstall it. Without full error message we cannot help much
